# change color legend matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, figure

I've to modify a figure, but I wouldn't like to recreate it since I have the .fig.

I would like to simply change the color of the legend maintaining the order.

for example I have

```
blue marker -> cluster 1

green marker -> cluster 2

red marker -> cluster 3

light blue marker -> cluster 4

magenta marker -> cluster 3
```

and I want to invert green and light blue

```
blue marker -> cluster 1

light blue marker -> cluster 2

red marker -> cluster 3

green marker -> cluster 4

magenta marker -> cluster 5
```

Is there any way to do this without create again the figure?

ps it's a scatterplot

[image]

you can download the figure here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJMS1feHFSaHp4R28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In What format do you have the figure?

Comment: I saved it fig jpeg and png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `Color` setting of the plots, it should change the legend automatically:

```
h = get(gca,'Children');
c = get(h,'Color');
```

`c` should be a cell array of colors. Presuming the handles are in the same order as the legend this should work:

```
set(h(2),'Color',c{4})
set(h(4),'Color',C{2})
```

Handle order can change depend how you created the figure, though, so you might want to just double-check which two you're swapping first.

---

What value you need to change depends on the exact type of plot. Usually it's just a matter of digging down into the `Children` for the axes to find the right bits to change.

In your case:

```
a = get(gca, 'Children');

q = get(a,'CData');
% there are six handles here
% I just looked at the CData and decided which to swap
set(a(3),'CData',q{5})
set(a(5),'CData',q{3})
```

Here, the first handle says what point is which so you'll need to swap those colors as well (thanks to Hoki for pointing out my error). Not the most elegant but a quick fix with `ismember`:

```
col = q{1};
col2 = col;
n3 = ismember(col, q{3},'rows');
n5 = ismember(col, q{5},'rows');
col2(find(n3),:)=repmat(q{5},[length(find(n3)) 1]);
col2(find(n5),:)=repmat(q{3},[length(find(n5)) 1]);
set(a(1),'CData',col2);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error 
"Error using specgraph.scattergroup/get
The name 'Color' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'scattergroup'."

Comment: In that case do `get(gca)` (you might need the children or just the axis details) and look for something like `CData` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to do it... I did h = get(gca), and I found ColorOrder, but then I don't know how to proceed..

Comment: I don't find CData, I added a link to download the figure...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJMS1feHFSaHp4R28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You needed to go down into the `Children`. I'll edit.

Comment: Be aware that you only change the color of the legend this way, not the color of the actual data points. All the 1001 data points are contained in the first handle, and their color are specified in the CData (1001x3) of the first handle. The 5 other handles are the one for each legend entry.

Comment: Ah, whoops! I didn't check closely - it works properly on the simple plot example. Thanks - I'll add an edit in a few minutes.